# How to connect a Groovy app to Meteor DDP?

Tags: java, groovy, meteor, ddp

I've got a Groovy app that is mature.  No chance of rewriting it in Meteor in the near term.  But I'd like to switch to Meteor for the UI.

There seems to be a lot of overlap between names that is confusing.  There was a [meteorframework](https://code.google.com/p/meteorframework/) written in Groovy in 2010, but that seems to have nothing to do with Meteor.  There are also an [Atmosphere framework](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) and a [Grails Atmosphere Meteor plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/atmosphere-meteor), but I don't think they have anything to do with DDP.  (Not sure about this.)  The [Atmosphere package site](https://atmospherejs.com/) is another unfortunate naming collision.

I did find a [Java DDP client](https://github.com/advantageous/ddp-client-java), but it requires Java 8, and I am not sure what's involved in moving my Groovy application to Java 8.

What would be the simplest way of adding DDP capabilities to my Groovy application, so that I can write the UI in Meteor?

Comment: Here is a simpler DDP client for Android, would it work for you? https://github.com/kenyee/android-ddp-client

Comment: I had seen that project, but my application runs on a Linux server, not in Android.  I'm not sure how much the fact that it's for Android is going to complicate things.  Have you ever tried using Android code in a server-side app?

Comment: I don't know anything about android, just wanted to bring to your attention